# Question about filter transformation

Tags: filter, high-pass-filter

I'm studying filters. In particular, I'm studying low-pass to high-pass filter transformation. I know that you only need to design an equivalent normalized low-pass filter and then, by using a suitable variable transformation, you can obtain the desired high-pass filter. Here a slide of the lecture:

[image]

**Question:** in this slide, the equivalent low-pass filter has an attenuation of 1dB at the normalized frequency 1. How is it possible to apply the Butterworth approximation? Indeed a normalized Butterworth filter necessarily has a 3db attenuation at the normalized frequency 1. It's impossible to have 1dB at the normalized frequency 1 for a normalized Butterworth filter!

Comment: hm your title says this is about the transformation, but your content says it's about the low-pass filter design. What is it? Or am I just misunderstanding?

Comment: Mark on your diagrams where you believe the cut-off frequency to be - put a red dot at the 3 dB point. Ask yourself what it really tells you.

Comment: Butterworth is not restricted to -3 dB, no filter is. It's just a convention which suits the Butterworth response perfectly, other fairly well, and yet others not very well. Just so you know, Butterworth and Chebyshev are not the only two filters in the world. Personally, I would take a grain of salt when reading lectures that say ***the** Butterworth or **the** Chebyshev*. Or *equilent* (but I also maek typos).